# Python generate all 3 letter combinations

Tags: python

I would like to get a list of all 3 letter combinations in a list, for example:

```
aaa, aab, aac
```

It must contain numbers aswell.
My code so far is

```
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
letters.extend([i+b+a for i in letters for b in letters for a in letters])
```

but this code returns combinations less than 3 digits, and no numbers.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @C_Z_ letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
letters.extend([i+b+a for i in letters for b in letters for a in letters])

This is stored in a list, which is OK for now but i wish to minimise ram usage.

Comment: Ok, please update your question with that code.

Comment: ```but with numbers in it too``` how do we know what numbers

Comment: @coderoftheday, I think he meant not numbers, but digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `combinations` in the standard library package `itertools`

```
import string
from itertools import combinations

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
letters.extend(string.digits)

for comb in combinations(letters, 3):
    print(''.join(comb))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use any packages, and this answer is derived from my answer on [creating selections from the elements of a list using a general number of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881363/creating-selections-from-the-elements-of-a-list-using-a-general-number-of-nested/64896515#64896515)

```
import string
import math
import random
l = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + [str(i) for i in range(10)]

new_list = []
n = len(l)
nCr = (math.factorial(n) / math.factorial(3) / math.factorial(n - 3))
while len(new_list) < int(nCr):
    co = [random.randint(0, len(l) - 1) for count in range(3)]
    if len(co) == len(set(co)) and co not in new_list:
        new_list.append(co)
final_list = []
for x in new_list:
    combination = [q for q in l if l.index(q) in x]
    final_list.append(combination)

print(sorted(final_list))
```

The list is sorted

I cant show the output because its too large

Comment: This works too, better to use for portability

Answer (score -1):

```
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase) 
for i in letters:
    for j in letters:
        for k in letters:
            s = i + j + k
```

'`s`' is the string you'll get while iterating.
You'll get all the combinations ***in an alphabetical order.***

Comment: This generates combinations lower than 3, such as a or b